# Why I'm not getting the nonce in the ID token when using the Sign In with Google One Tap UX in ITP browsers / Safari?

Tags: google-oauth, google-signin, google-identity, sign-in-with-google

I have a test web app, with the Sign In with Google button + One Tap UX  configured with a [data-nonce](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/html-reference#data-nonce) :

```
      <div
        id="g_id_onload"
        data-client_id="<%=google_client_id%>"
        data-context="signin"
        data-ux_mode="popup"
        data-login_uri="<%=site_address%>/sign-in-with-google-callback"
        data-nonce="<%=idTokenNonce%>"
        data-itp_support="true"
      ></div>

      <div
        class="g_id_signin"
        data-type="standard"
        data-shape="rectangular"
        data-theme="outline"
        data-text="signin_with"
        data-size="large"
        data-logo_alignment="left"
      ></div>
```

On Chrome (and the other non-ITP browsers) both buttons work properly and I receive the ID token (JWT) that contains a claim `nonce` with the nonce that I specified when rendering the page.

On Safari (ITP) with "Prevent cross-site tracking" **the regular button produces a id token that has the nonce**. But if I login **using the One Tap ([upgraded One Tap UX  on ITP browsers](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/features#upgraded_ux_on_itp_browsers))** I get a ID token but that **JWT does not contain any `nonce` claim**.

Is there anything I could do to get the nonce to work also for the "upgraded One Tap UX on ITP browsers"?

Comment: It is not possible to get a nonce in the ID token when using the upgraded One Tap UX on ITP browsers. This is because the nonce is only included in the ID token if the user directly signs in to your app using the Google Sign-In button, and this is not the case when using the upgraded One Tap UX.

Comment: Is that documented somewhere? Also do you know why? I mean is there any technical  the difference between the Google SignIn button and the button in the upgrade One Tap UX?  I don't understand why they would be any different.